Regex to select all text that is not between two phrases
I need to scan text files and pull their text, but there are certain sections I want to ignore.
The sections to ignore start with:
--- start private ---
and end with:
--- end private ---
I don't mind if the start and end phrases are included or not.
Example
test1
test2
--- start private ---
this text should not be returned by the regex
--- end private ---
test3
test4
--- start private ---
this text should also not be returned by the regex
--- end private ---
test5

Only the lines starting with "test" should be returned.
I have the .net 6 flavour of Regex to do this with, but I don't have access to the .net code. I can only use regex to get what I need

The canonical approach in .NET would be to just remove the stuff between start and end with a regular expression replacement, leaving just the lines you want. I have linked your question to a duplication question that describes how to do that. Since you have line breaks in between, you might need to add the Singleline flag.

I don't have access to the code. Only the regex that can be used

Ah, ok. I've reopened your question then. That's difficult. Maybe some trick like that would work, but it won't be pretty.

Did you try out any patters that did not work?

I think you are looking for this Regex.Replace(input, @"--- start private ---[\s\S]*?--- end private ---\s*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline); .. the regex is pretty trivial made like that but there's still the chance of false positives because there's no strict condition on the fact that the end marking should be at the beginning of a newline. If you need something else you have to split the lines and process them one by one keeping track of begin and end markings

@DiegoD: That's what I suggested in my duplicate link, and that's what OP said won't work: OP can't do a Regex.Replace, they can just do a Regex.Match and collect the results.

@Heinzi thanks for clarifying.. well then he can only split the lines and begin a finite states machine.. while iterating those lines when a "start private" is found, prevent returning the next lines until "end private" is found. It would not even need regex there

frankly speaking, I don't have access to the code. Only the regex that can be used ..is pretty vague anyway.. and doesn't deserve further attention

@DiegoD: Good point. On the other hand, it's a nice regex puzzle, and I like puzzles.

"I don't have access to the code. Only the regex that can be used" What does that even mean? If you don't have access to the code, where would you use the regex? And if you can use the regex in a "certain place" why can't you use other code there?

This could also work if data follows the pattern: (?m)(?>(?:^(?!---).+\n*)+)(?!--- end)

@derpirscher: I'm configuring an inhouse app to collect data. I don't have access to the code and the very sensible suggestions you have made aren't getting on a roadmap any time soon. I know it's contrived, but these constraints do make for a challenging puzzle :)

The canonical approach in .NET would be to use Regex.Replace to replace everything that starts with --- start private --- and ends with --- end private --- with an empty string, leaving just the lines you want.
However, you mention in your question that you cannot use Regex.Replace, you can just parameterize an existing call to Regex.Match. So we need to get creative.

This should do it:
(?s)(^|--- end private ---).*?(--- start private ---|$)

It matches everything that

starts at the start of the document (^) or with --- end private --- and
ends with --- start private --- or the end of the document ($).

(?s) is the single line flag to ensure that newlines are also matched by ..
The question mark at the end of .*? ensures that the match is non-greedy. Otherwise the regex would just match everything from the start to the end of the document.
If you want to exclude the separator lines, you can use look-ahead/look-behind assertions for matching the separator texts:
(?s)(^|(?<=--- end private ---)).*?((?=--- start private ---)|$)


You surely deserved the upvote... my considerations among comments were targeted to the OP of course. The regex you shared correctly works with Regex.Matches .. just missing to remove the markings but you talked about that in the answer

@DiegoD: I've also added an example for the latter (without the markings) - OP doesn't care whether the markings are there or not, but it might be useful for other readers. I'll leave the simple version as well since it's easier to understand.

Thank you for this. I'll let you know how my testing goes
